# How can Microsoft Wi-Fi Sense share just the internet connection?

Tags: wifi, windows-10

According to the [Wi‑Fi Sense FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq)

> When you share network access, your contacts get Internet access only.
>   For example, if you share your home Wi-Fi network, your contacts won't
>   have access to other computers, devices, or files stored on your home
>   network. If you have a small business that has intranet sites, your
>   contacts won’t be able to access them.

How does that work? Does the guest computer connect to the sharing computer directly?

Comment: We've had heartbleed and now we have Windows 10.

Comment: That is the smartest and funniest IT comment in history :D:D:D @DeerHunter

Answer (score 1):

MS Wi-Fi Sense is simply going to share your pre-shared key for your Wireless network with the contacts that you have stored (Outlook, Facebook, and Bing I think?) so that your (presumed) friend can use your network without having to manually tell them the pre-shared key.

Now - the reason Microsoft states that your guest won't be able to access other computers, devices, or files store on your home network is because Network Discovery is turned off by default once someone connects to your network using Wi-Fi Sense. So, it would be more difficult, but certainly not impossible or even that challenging for someone with average skill level to see other computers and devices on your network once they are connected up.

And also, no, the guest computer does not connect directly to the computer. It's going to connect to your wireless router just like normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it even states that intranet websites are not accessible, so does that mean it blocks access to the intranet on the guests computer? (Which would offer some protection - weak but enough to be justify such an FAQ entry.)

Comment: If there is an intranet website inside of the network that the guest is currently connected to, I would say that they WOULD be able to access this by default, even with Windows Network Discovery turned off by default for Wi-Fi Sense. What Microsoft is saying in their disclosure is that, by default, Network Discovery will be turned off so the user cannot see DEVICES inside of the network. But I imagine you could turn Network Discovery on very easily, or even just connect to the devices if you discovered the host name or IP of the device inside of the network.

Comment: @AndreKR as far as I can tell, this is nothing more than a variant of DRM

Answer (score 0):

> How does that work? Does the guest computer connect to the sharing
>   computer directly?

Quoted from the [FAQ](http://investmentwatchblog.com/windows-10-shares-your-wi-fi-with-contacts/):

> For networks you choose to share access to, the password is sent over
>   an encrypted connection and stored in an encrypted file on a Microsoft
>   server, and then sent over a secure connection to your contacts’ phone
>   if they use Wi-Fi Sense and they’re in range of the Wi-Fi network you
>   shared.

As for your question's title, it is up to you to decide to trust or not Microsft when it says the Wi-Fi Sense will block your contacts from sharing your network resources (such as your computer). But the other serious problem is that if a computer (contact) connects to your network knows the key: if so, it is feasible that a hacker can get the key too somewhere in your system and thus have access to your network.